# Subtracting large numbers result in NaN JS

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and I was trying to make some sort of a clicking test site.
This is the code I came up with:

```
var counter = 0;
document.getElementById("click").onclick = function() {
    if (!isActivated) {
        isActivated = true;
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getTime();
        console.log(n);
        console.log(typeof n)
    }
    counter++;
    document.getElementById("click").innerHTML = counter;
    var x = new Date();
    var y = x.getTime();
    console.log(y);
    console.log(typeof y);
    var difference = y - n;
    console.log(y - n);
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = difference;
}
document.getElementById("stop").onclick = function() {
    isActivated = false;
    alert("Your score was: " + counter / difference / 1000 + "cps.");
    counter = 0;
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = 0;
    document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = 0;
}
```

id "click" is a button that displays the click count
id "time" is a paragraph that displays the time passed
id "stop" is a button that stops the time and shows the result.

In my eyes, everything should work just fine, but I got these awkward logs running the program:

```
1618677241469
script.js:9 number
script.js:15 1618677241469
script.js:16 number
script.js:18 0
script.js:15 1618677242492
script.js:16 number
script.js:18 NaN
script.js:15 1618677243401
script.js:16 number
script.js:18 NaN
```

Subtracting the initial time from the current time at click for some reason gave me a NaN??
I'm probably missing something here but I can't tell, I started JavaScript yesterday.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: `n` is a local variable inside the "click" handler that is only given a value when `isActivated` is not true. Thus, on subsequent clicks, `n` is `undefined`.

Comment: Try the snippet `console.log("y = ", y, ", n = ", n, ", y - n = ", difference)` after `difference` is calculated. This would help you in debugging actual issue. In chrome browser `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is `9007199254740991`, the value in question is still within safe range.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks a lot, I made n a global variable and it worked